# Hierarchical query to return parent activity and dependent activities

Tags: sql, postgresql, hierarchical-data, recursive-query

I have to Create a function that take activity_id as an argument.

Function should return activity direct predecessor and indirect predecessors and their relationship and with all the sub activities that exists in tree hierarchy.
All the sub activities with predecessors in a hierarchical way.

My table structure is as follows:

Predecessor

```
CREATE TABLE public.predecessor
(
predecessor_id integer NOT NULL ,
current_activity_id integer,
dependent_activity_id integer,
createdby integer,
created_at timestamp without time zone NOT NULL DEFAULT now()
)
```

Activities

```
CREATE TABLE public.activities
(
activity_id integer NOT NULL,
parent_id integer,
name text,
type_id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT 11
)
```

I know its a very brief representation but i will appreciate quick answers or guidelines to formulate a query.

Sample Data in Tables is as follows

Activities Data

```
activity_id|parent_id
   8000|    |            
   8100|8000|            
   8200|8000|            
   8120|8100|            
   8130|8100|            
   8140|8100|            
   8220|8200|            
   8230|8200|            
   8240|8200|            
   8241|8240|            
   8242|8240|            
   8243|8240|            
   7000|    |            
   7100|7000|            
   7200|7000|            
   7300|7000|            
   7210|7200|            
   7220|7200|            
   6100|6000|            
   6200|6000|            
   6210|6200|            
   6220|6200|            
   6230|6200|            
   6240|6200|            
   6241|6240|            
   6242|6240|            
   6243|6240|            
   6244|6240|
```

Predecessor Data

```
activity_id|parent_id
8100|8120
8100|8130
8100|8140
8200|8220
8200|8230
8200|8240
7000|7100
7000|7200
7000|7300
6200|6210
6200|6220
6200|6230
6200|6240
6240|6241
6240|6242
6240|6243
6240|6244
```

Answer (score 0):

Created two functions, one for getting ancestors or predecessors of an activity and other to get descendants or successors of an activity.

Function **get_activity_anc** (act_id is passed and then all predecessor or ancestor activities are retrieved)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.get_activity_anc(IN act_id integer)
  RETURNS TABLE(activity_id integer, parent_id integer) AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
    RETURN QUERY
    WITH RECURSIVE results(activity_id, parent_id) AS
    (
        SELECT  act.activity_id,
            act.parent_id
        FROM    activities act
        WHERE act.activity_id = act_id
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  t.activity_id,
            t.parent_id
        FROM    activities t
            INNER JOIN results r ON r.parent_id = t.activity_id
    )
    -- output the results
    SELECT  res.activity_id, res.parent_id
    FROM    results res
    ORDER BY activity_id;

END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
```

Function **get_activity_desc** (act_id is passed and then all descendants or successors activities are retrieved)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.get_activity_desc(IN act_id integer)
  RETURNS TABLE(activity_id integer, parent_id integer, level integer, path_info integer[]) AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
     RETURN QUERY
     WITH RECURSIVE rel_tree(activity_id, parent_id, level, path_info) AS (
               SELECT activities.activity_id,
                   activities.parent_id,
                   0 AS level,
                   sortorder || array[activities.activity_id]   as path_info
                  FROM activities
                 WHERE activities.parent_id =act_id
          UNION ALL
               SELECT c.activity_id,
                   c.parent_id,
                   p.level + 1,
                   p.path_info || c.sortorder ||c.activity_id
                  FROM activities c
                JOIN rel_tree p ON c.parent_id = p.activity_id
          )
          select * from rel_tree s order by path_info;
END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
```

Function **get_activity_ancdesc** to get both ancestors and descendants of an activity

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.get_activity_ancdesc(IN act_id integer)
  RETURNS TABLE(activity_id integer, parent_id integer) AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
    RETURN QUERY
    WITH ANCESTOR_DESC AS 
    (
        select ga.activity_id, ga.parent_id from get_activity_anc(act_id) ga
        union
        select gad.activity_id, gad.parent_id from get_activity_desc(act_id) gad
    )
    select * from ANCESTOR_DESC AD
    ORDER BY AD.activity_id;
END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
```